# AHK Hotkey's expression in string, separate commands without spaces

Tags: string, variables, autohotkey, hotkeys

Alright, so I have this part of my code:

```
SetGrenade:
    gui, 2: Submit, NoHide
    if Flashbang 
        CurrentNade := "send 4|Sleep 20|send 4|Sleep 1000|Send {LButton}|Sleep 100|send 1"
    else if Smoke 
        CurrentNade := "Send 4|Sleep 20|Send 4|Sleep 20|Send 4|Sleep 1000|Send {LButton}|Sleep 100|Send 1"
    else ;He
        CurrentNade := "send 4|Sleep 1000|Send {LButton}|Sleep 100|Send 1"
return
```

(Hotkey for this is xbutton1)
And everything works good except that this '|' vertical bar is used to separate commands but it ALSO places a space. For example:
User chooses option 1 (Flashbang) when he clicks xbutton1 on his mouse he gets this:
 4 4  1
not
441 (I skipped the sleeps and clicks because they arent shown in notepad.)

Is there a way to fix this?
I tried removing the vertical bars (|) but then the code is placed as a text.
Please help,
regards,
Adam

EDIT:
Full code:

```
#SingleInstance force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
CurrentNade := 0
;GUI
Gui, Show, w200 h300, sAHK v0.2
Gui, Add, checkbox, gAutoNade vAutoNade cBlue, Enable Auto-Grenade
Gui, Add, button, vSettingsButton gSettings, View Settings
Gui, Add, button, gUpcoming, View Upcoming Functions

Hotkey, xbutton1, CurrentNade, Off

Gui, 2:Hide
Gui, 2:Add, Text, cBlue, Auto-Grenade To Throw:
Gui, 2:Add, radio, gSetGrenade vFlashbang, Flashbang
Gui, 2:Add, radio, gSetGrenade vSmoke, Smoke Grenade
Gui, 2:Add, radio, gSetGrenade vHe, Explosive Grenade

OnExit, GuiClose

return

;END GUI

;EXPRESSION

Settings:
WinGetPos, guiPosX, guiPosY,,, A
guiPosX := guiPosX + 200
Gui, 2:Show, x%guiPosX% y%guiPosY% Restore
Gui, 2:Show, w200 h300, Script Settings
return

AutoNade:
    gui, Submit, NoHide
    if AutoNade
    {
        SoundPlay, %A_ScriptDir%/snd-EN/SL.wav
    Hotkey, xbutton1, On
    }
    else
    {
    Hotkey, xbutton1, Off
    SoundPlay, %A_ScriptDir%/snd-EN/ST.wav
    }   
return

CurrentNade:
    ;MsgBox %CurrentNade%
    Loop, Parse, CurrentNade,|
    {
    if instr(A_LoopField,"send")
        send % SubStr(A_LoopField, 5)
    else
        Sleep SubStr(A_LoopField, 6)
    }
return

SetGrenade:
    gui, 2: Submit, NoHide
    if Flashbang 
        CurrentNade := "send 4|Sleep 20|send 4|Sleep 1000|Send {LButton}|Sleep 100|send 1"
    else if Smoke 
        CurrentNade := "Send 4|Sleep 20|Send 4|Sleep 20|Send 4|Sleep 1000|Send {LButton}|Sleep 100|Send 1"
    else ;He
        CurrentNade := "send 4|Sleep 1000|Send {LButton}|Sleep 100|Send 1"
return

Upcoming:
Gui, Upcoming:Add, Text,, 1. Overall impovements, UI updates, bug fixes and small changes
Gui, Upcoming:Add, Text,, 2. Bunny Hop
Gui, Upcoming:Add, Text,, 3. 180 turnaround
Gui, Upcoming:Add, Text,, 4. Recoil Reducer (RCS)
Gui, Upcoming:Show
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

;END EXPRESSION
```

Comment: the code you've shown doesn't do anything. it only defines the value of `currentNade` as a string. what is supposed to happen with this variable? can you show that part of the code, please?

Comment: Placed the full code, sorry, forgotten 'bout that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr` in AutoHotKey is 1-based as per [documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Functions.htm#SubStr):

> For StartingPos, specify 1 to start at the first character

Simply increase the index in your code by 1:

```c
if instr(A_LoopField,"send")
    send % SubStr(A_LoopField, 6)
else
    sleep SubStr(A_LoopField, 7)
}
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you very much! I wouldn't think of that.